# ASP.Net website - doesn't load css file correctly

Tags: html, css, asp.net

I'm having issues with this website, it seems like the css and image files (all located in the *../Content/* folder. Which is strange because I've never seen this error on other servers I tested the site on.

Problem is I don't have direct access to that problematic server and can only guess from here what might be wrong.

The site is hosted by a local IIS and invoked by http://localhost/application-name/site-name

The css file is referenced in the master file below, and the images are referenced e.g. *~/Content/images/sample.png*

**Site Master**

```
<html lang="en">
<head runat="server">
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title><%: Page.Title %> - Stackoverfl0w</title>

    <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server">
        <%: Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr") %>
    </asp:PlaceHolder>

    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="Stylesheets" runat="server">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/Content/Site.css" type="text/css" />
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>

    <webopt:bundlereference runat="server" path="~/Content/css" />

    <link href="~/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />

</head>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The IIS server was missing the **Static Content** feature, which was enabled with all other test installations by default.

After enabling it via **Windows Features** the issue was resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Use the ~ symbol on file path, so browser can fetch the file from main directory....

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Content/Site.css" type="text/css" />
```