# How to load correctly my css asp.net Visual Basic

Tags: css, asp.net, vb.net

Yesterday I was working on my college project, everything was running smooth so I decided to upload it to github where my partner could access it. Today I opened the local repo and suddenly my CSS wasn't displaying correctly. I'm using **Bootstrap 4**.

This is how it looks now:

[image: Here is how it looks now]

This is how it should look:

[image: How it should be]

I've been using a **Bootstrap** template. I already tried making a new **CSS** file but it doesn't change. Also using this post [ASP.Net website - doesn't load css file correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44965416/asp-net-website-doesnt-load-css-file-correctly)

How I was calling my css

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
```

I tried

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/style.css">
```

Even

```
<head runat="server">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/style.css" runat="server">
</head>
```

[Css folder is located in asp default folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I1ckB.png)

Comment: Please showcase how you are referencing the CSS file in your `index` (or similar), along with also showcasing where exactly the CSS file is stored relative to your index. Finally, make sure your have actually included it in the project.

Comment: Try adding this to your CSS link  tag: type: text/css. Also try putting absolute path, meaning if your css file is in C Drive within Styles folder try writing it as C:\Styles\style.css.

Answer (score 0):

Well, after a little attempt, it looks like the project had been corrupted when it was loaded. Since I had finished it on time, I created a new project and include the previous files. 
It works like a charm.